# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinkoff.invest'; 'tinkoff' is not a package

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I have trouble with tinkoff API 2.0.
Venv does not see tinkoff-investments, but it was installed successfully.

What did I try:

- downgrade from 3.10 to 3.8 python version
- update from 3.10 to 3.10.7
- deleted and installed module tinkoff-investments

CODE:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xCEj.jpg)

```py
from tinkoff.invest import Client

TOKEN = 'my_token'

with Client(TOKEN) as client:

    print(client.users.get_accounts())
```

Comment: Have you installed the package within your venv or have you installed it on your global versions of python. The package will need to be installed again within your venv

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tinkoff.invest'; 'tinkoff' is not a package
```

may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `tinkoff.py` and try to run it as `python tinkoff.py` **or** another file has the name `tinkoff.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, **rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module**.

---

In your case, according to the screenshot, you run the file `tinkoff.py`, which has this line about import:

```py
from tinkoff.invest import Client
```

Python sees import and **first thing** (as described above in documentation at link) Python does is look `invest` at this file — `tinkoff.py`, not in module `tinkoff` you installed in venv or in `Python310\Libs\..`. It looks like Python trying to import the same file into itself and finds only the `TOKEN` variable and not `invest` object.
So simply rename your startup file `tinkoff.py` to something else, for example to `tinkoffApp.py`, to avoid the similarity of the name with the imported module.

Comment: Thank you! I've spend an hour trying to figure out.